# PHP Global doesn't keep UTF-8 encoding

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I want to load my "language" file which is basically an assiciative array as global variable.

```
global $i18n;

$i18n = array(
    // status = success
    "success_login_completed" => "Du wurdest erfolgreich eingeloggt.",
    ...
}
```

When i later use it for example like this:

```
private static function translateInternal($key) {
    global $i18n;

    if($i18n[$key]) {
        return $i18n[$key];
    }

    return $key;
}
```

I receive non utf-8 responses like this: ... Sie alle ben\u00f6tigten Felder  ...

Response Content Type is: text/html; charset=UTF-8

However, when i directly dump the $i18n variable after declaring it, the encoding is correct. It seems to be a problem with the global visiblity...

Comment: have you set the language files encoding to utf-8 ?

Comment: Yes i did so - including every other file which is included within a call

Comment: Have you checked the encoding of your source files?